# How to move k3s' ingress to another port

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I'm trying to use k3s as a replacement for minikube since there is a bug that spikes the CPU. The machine on which I'm deploying already has a docker-compose set of services bound to 443 and 80. k3s' traefik superceeds that bind and prevents my access to the existing services.

I want to move k3s' traefik to alternative ports. I've tried to stop traefik with `sudo k3s server --no-deploy traefik` but get *Error: failed to create listener: failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:6444: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6444: bind: address already in use*

Answer (score 0):

You did not stop the k3s service prior to running the `sudo k3s server --no-deploy traefik` command. This command simply starts a new server with the embedded traefik disabled. You'll have to stop the instance that was started before.

Using systemd, you'd stop the running instance using `sudo systemctl stop k3s`.

If you want to manually control when k3s is started, I'd recommend disabling the k3s service so that it doesn't get started automatically. To do so, run `sudo systemctl disable k3s`.

If you want k3s to still automatically start on boot up, edit the file at `/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service` and add the `--no-deploy traefik` option after the `server` command at the bottom of the file.